# PHP: Url as parameter

Tags: php, rest, crud

I'm building a small restful api and I'm asking if it's possible to seperate the url to php file and the end of the url.

E.g. `www.mydomain.com/api/parameter/1/2/`

In this case the php file is adressed with `www.mydomain.com/api/` or `www.mydomain.com/api/index.php` and `parameter/1/2/` is the parameter.

I want a CRUD interface so that GET without parameter gets a list of all data. To achieve this I need to check if a parameter is attached and to extract the parameter.

Other example

`www.mydomain.com/topics/` => gets all topics

`www.mydomain.com/topics/1/posts/` => gets all posts of topic 1,

`www.mydomain.com/topics/1/posts/2/` => gets post 2 of topic 1

My question is: Is it possible and how?

Comment: Then have try! Not a single questionmark in your question....

Comment: you mean `/api/parameter/1/2` -> `somescript.php?parameter=1&parameter=2`?

Comment: Did you have problems with the `.htaccess` or are there any problems to filter `GET` within PHP? Did you code something?

Comment: Im sure a variety of wonky home grown solutions will show up below, but this has been written and rewritten thousands of times by people smarter than you or me. Just google 'php router', or use one of the many many existing (micro)frameworks out there, eg slim, fatfreephp, lumen, silex, etc etc

Comment: I mean a behaviour like in Laravel where that way is used to get data from database. E.g. you got a database with topics and posts. 

www.mydomain.com/topics/ => gets all topics,
www.mydomain.com/topics/1/posts => gets all posts of topic 1,
www.mydomain.com/topics/1/posts/2 => gets post 2 of topic 1

That's all done in one php file.

Comment: Laravel uses the symfony router. Lumen uses fastroute. Dont make your own cruddy version. Why not actually use Laravel/Lumen if thats what you want?

Comment: I wanted to write a very small api for development and testing. I thought that Laravel or Lumen would be to big for a small task but now I think it is the only solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably have to read the request URI from the end of the URL using `$_SERVER['request_uri']`. This would return `/api/parameter/1/2`. You could then substring it if the length is reliable, or use a regex with `preg_match` to get just the parameter section. e.g.

```
preg_match("parameter\/.*", $_SERVER['request_uri'], $matches)
```

would return either the string `parameter/1/2` in the $matches variable, or `false` if no match was found

But yeah like others are saying, you're probably better using GET parameters if you can, and just do a check using `isset()` to see if there are any parameters.

Comment: That way is very static. You can't change the structure of the backend. But I fear it's the only solution.